# scala script execution in IDE

Tags: scala, scala-ide

I have just started Scala programming.
This is basic example which is most popular I believe.

I am using Eclipse Scala IDE. I don't understand what type of file I should create for Scala Script from Menu. Is Scala script a Scala File or Scala Class or Scala worksheet or Scala application? Could you please confirm.

```
// code-examples/IntroducingScala/shapes-actor-script.scala
import shapes._
ShapeDrawingActor.start()
ShapeDrawingActor ! new Circle(new Point(0.0,0.0), 1.0)
ShapeDrawingActor ! new Rectangle(new Point(0.0,0.0), 2, 5)
ShapeDrawingActor ! new Triangle(new Point(0.0,0.0),
 new Point(1.0,0.0),
 new Point(0.0,1.0))
ShapeDrawingActor ! 3.14159
ShapeDrawingActor ! "exit"
```

Thanks,
Chandra

Comment: Looks like your example comes from "Programming Scala". It's a long way into the book. Why not start with the simpler examples earlier rather than diving straight into actors?

Comment: Take a look at [IntelliJ IDEA Scala plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+for+IntelliJ+IDEA) as well. Though syntax highlighting have still some problems you can create Scala Scripts.

Comment: Removed the extra content from the source, changed the case of the I-s. Added Scala-ide tag to reflect the subject of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Chandra,

The easiest way for beginners to start with Eclipse is to use the [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/), which is Eclipse pre-configured with Scala.

From there, you can create a new scala project, then right click on the directory where you want your file, to create a new Scala file.